# Setting Inner Div width's percentage of parent

Tags: html

I have 2 parent div's. (parent-left and parent-right). Parent left is 50px and parent right takes up remaining screen width, so I set it to 100%.

I have 2 child/inner divs within parent-right. I need it to take 85% and 15% of the parent-right's width but it calculates percentage based on screen width. What am I doing wrong?

Code below:

```
<div class="row clearfix">

<div id='parent-left' style="width:50px;float:left;background-color:blue;"><span> parent-left </span>
</div>

<div id='parent-right' style="width:100%;">
  <div id='inner-left' style="width:85%;float:left;background-color:green;"><span> inner1</span></div>
  <div id='parent-right' style="width:15%;float:left;background-color:gray"><span> inner2</span></div>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: There are two #parent-right id

Comment: If you want to exactly use 85% and 15%, you can use css calc() [Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9mwBt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not set a `width` for the `#parent-right` element, instead set a `left-margin` equal to the `width` of the `#parent-left` element.

```
<div id='parent-right' style="margin-left:50px;">
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5J38g/

Comment: awesome your solution works! can you please tell me why the 100% on parent-right would cause issues with child? Just to get a technical understanding....

Comment: setting 100% to the right does not make it take the remaining of the screen, it makes it take all of the screen. Only its contents are affected by the `#parent-left` element. You can see that if you add a background color to the right div and push the left one down.. ***See http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/v4Jrh/***

Comment: @user3658423 It's generally bad practice to stylize content inline with HTML. You should always try to separate your CSS from your HTML using either external style sheets or `<style>` tags. You should also never give two elements the same ID (parent-right). I'm guessing that was a typo, though.