# How to specify wdith of inner divs as percentage?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something like following, that is specify the width of inner div as a percentage of the parent div.

```
<div>
    <div style="width: 20%">
        some text
    </div>
    <div style="width: 80%">
        Some more text
    </div>
</div>
```

How to do this so that the inner divs stay inside the parent div?  I tried adding float to the inner divs.  if I did that the inner divs go outside the parent div.  I do not wish to specify width as pixels.

I saw the following:
[Setting Inner Div width's percentage of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24376524/setting-inner-div-widths-percentage-of-parent)

What I am trying to do could be a bit different.  I am open to using something like bootstrap to achieve this.

Comment: Try adding `style="position: relative;"` on the outer div?

Comment: Use the column structure for your divs. 
There are specific classes  that adjusts the width are required.
Also, provide with a jsfiddle/codepen link showing what you have made and what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using flexbox! first off all we need to update your markup all little bit adding some class names

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">
        some text
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
        Some more text
    </div>
</div>
```

then you need to give to the parent div a display flex, you can add a height too

```
.parent{
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
}
```

and for the last you give the child divs the width you want

```
.child1{
  width: 20%;
}

.child2{
  width: 80%;
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/LXREar) you have a codepen if you want to check it, and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) an article you can read about flexbox and how it works!

Comment: You don't have to set the width of the parent div. Divs have an automatic width of 100%.

Comment: Yes you are right, it's a habit that I have, but I don't think it's wrong to do it.

Comment: The problem is when you add padding and/or margin to your div. [See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17468733/difference-between-width-auto-and-width-100-percent)

Comment: Thanks for that question, I've never paid attention to that because I always use boxing size: border-box, but I do not know if OP is using it, I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want the divs to appear inline?  If my assumption is correct you can use float and inline-block.

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="div1">some text</div>
    <div id="div2">some more text</div>
  </div>
```

Following style:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#div1 {
  background: pink;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#div2 {
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 80%;
}
```

See here: https://jsbin.com/xipinaj/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Though flexbox is a more elegant solution, @MartinBA's solution is better.  Im just showing an alternative.

Answer (score -1):

If your using bootstrap its recommended to use the bootstraps feature for doing this. You can easily build this with bootstrap grid

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/